# Angular Material 15 form field floating label scale

Tags: css, sass, angular-material

I'm in the very difficult process of upgrading Angular Material 14 to 15 components (migration from legacy to MDC implementation).

Up to this point, I played with CSS selector priorities to override the Material styles, for instance to reduce the height of the form fields :

```
mat-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-outline div.mat-mdc-form-field-infix {
  padding: 3px 0 0 0;
  min-height: 0;
}
```

While tedious (and maybe not the best way of doing this), this has worked quite fine for most of the components. However, I'm facing an issue with the form fields floating labels, specifically this part of the Material generated CSS :

```
.mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper.mdc-text-field--outlined .mdc-notched-outline--upgraded .mdc-floating-label--float-above {
    --mat-mdc-form-field-label-transform: translateY(-32.75px)
          scale(var(--mat-mdc-form-field-floating-label-scale, 0.75));
    transform: var(--mat-mdc-form-field-label-transform);
}
```

The 75% scale has the side effect of making all the labels "blurry", which is quite annoying for readabilily.

Using CSS, I could override the scale to avoid the 0.75 and set 1.0 instead, while reducing the font-size to fixed 13px. The label would now be perfectly displayed withtout the "blurry" effect. However, the label would grow larger than the white gap in the form field border. This is due to this part of the form field component :

```
<div class="mdc-notched-outline__notch" 
    style="width: calc(45px * var(--mat-mdc-form-field-floating-label-scale, 0.75) + 9px);">
        <label ...><mat-label ...>Name</mat-label></label>
</div>
```

The 45px is logically calculated according to the number of characters in the label (here `Name`). But the final width also consider the floating label scaling (`--mat-mdc-form-field-floating-label-scale`).

If I understand correctly, the only solution to change the floating label scaling while changing the gap size is to override the `--mat-mdc-form-field-floating-label-scale`. Unfortunately I'm unable to understand how I can override such value in the [Angular Material Theming Documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming). I'm not even sure it is the correct documentation for what I'm looking for.

I opened the same question on the [Angular Material Github](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26549).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also struggled with this problem to override **--mat-mdc-form-field-floating-label-scale**.

For me, it works this way:

```
.mat-mdc-form-field {
    --mat-mdc-form-field-floating-label-scale: 0.76;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

I just came across this issue and noticed the ccs property `will-change` caused the blurry text. I changed it from `transform` to `auto` and that fixed the blurry text.

```
.mdc-floating-label {
  ...
  will-change: auto;
}
```

Comment: It seems to work on most of my cases (not all, need to dig why). This is indeed very good to know. Never heard of "will-change" CSS property before... I can't accept your solution because it's not an answer to my original question (which was answered by Fabren), but it might help avoiding a label scale change (which is tedious) ! Thanks a lot !